# jQuery UI Sortable - Get currently moved div ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to get the ID of the sorted div.
I currenly have the position...

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="item1" class="col-md-4 red">1</div>
        <div id="item2" class="col-md-4 blue">2</div>
        <div id="item3" class="col-md-4 black">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $( ".row" ).sortable();
    $( ".row" ).disableSelection(); 

    $(".row").sortable({
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            alert("New position: " + ui.item.index());

        }
    });

});

</script>
```

How can I get the ID?

Comment: `alert("ID: " + ui.item.attr('id'));`

Comment: @Hazonko is right, but you should really be using `console.log()`

Comment: This is true. I just c/p'd his first alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery UI the `ui.item` is the instance of the object.  You can access it directly with:

```
var id = ui.item.attr('id');
```

Likewise anything else you'd want to get.